# How can volume attributes be transferred correctly with RPT?

Tags: ocean, petrel

It seems to me that volume attributes (with an IIdentifiable TArgPack) can't be copied to a background project through RPT, unless I'm missing something.

SeismicAttribute.CreateArgumentPackage() has no context of IDataSourceManager, so it seems impossible to know when the created argument package is destined for the background project.  We've realized that our code simply uses DataManager.DataSourceManager when instantiating the TArgPack, which works fine as long as the attribute is copied *from* the background project, but results in a non-working attribute volume when copied *to* the background project.

The SeismicAttributes sample in the SDK uses a Serializable TArgPack, which probably does not exhibit this problem, as the instance is implicitly serialized in the correct project context.

Known issue?  Workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Robert, this will be addressed in 2015.1.

CreateArgumentPackage() will be obsoleted and replaced with CreateArgumentPackage(IDataSoruceManager).

Updating your code to use the new CreateArgumentPackage(IDataSourceManager) will be enough for it to participate in RPT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a known issue and will be fixed in 2015.1.

Regards,
Deng